Audi a3 2009 1.6 bse engine
Audi a3 1.6 no acceleration in 2nd gear when push clutch in and out it will start accelerating again or other option is to change to 3rd gear then it’s fine

Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! When the vehicle isn't accelerating as you are saying, does the engine sound as though it is going faster (ie: engines revs but the car isn't going faster)?

No it just won’t accelerate until i push clutch in and out then it’s fine or change gear this only happens in 2nd gear
